# How do I count by frequency of a letter in index in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, increment

lets say you're giving 5 inputs like so:

```
hello
hullo
zeros
```

It is then stored into a list like so `['hello','hullo','zeros']`
I would like it to return a dictionary that counts the frequency of the letter in their index. It should return something like this

```
{h:2,z:1} {e:2,u:1} {l:2,r:1} {l:2,o:1} {o:2,s:1}
```

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: That looked like 3 inputs, is the input a string? An array? Individual variables?

Comment: I want to too, but i dont know how to. Sorry, first time using stack

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = ['hello','hullo','zeros']
final_data = [{d:''.join(i).count(d) for d in ''.join(i)} for i in zip(*s)]
```

Output:

```
[{'h': 2, 'z': 1}, {'u': 1, 'e': 2}, {'r': 1, 'l': 2}, {'l': 2, 'o': 1}, {'s': 1, 'o': 2}]
```

Edit: functional method:

```
def get_count(the_index, the_list):
   listing = [i[the_index] for i in the_list]
   return {a:listing.count(a) for a in listing}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but do you mind explaining to me what exactly final_data is doing?

Comment: Is there also a dumber and more elaborate way to do this function?

Comment: @WangWang `final_data` is creating the list of dictionaries, which are storing the number of times each char occurs in the row. `zip` is transposing the data, which means that we can access its contents by row, rather than by column. Regarding "dumber", could you clarify what that would entail? This is about as elaborate as it can get, although there are other ways of solving this using one-liners.

Comment: sorry I just started coding. For each string in the
list, the function counts the number of times each character occurs at the specified index (for example, if the index is 4, the function will look at the fifth character of each string). You may assume that the index value always falls into the range 0–(string length - 1), inclusive.Create a dictionary where each key is a lowercase letter; the value of each key is the number of strings that have that letter in the specified position. return the dictionary of letter frequencies that was just generated

Comment: if you can use my other ways to do, that would be very helpful

Comment: @WangWang no problem! Keep it up! Please see my recent edit.

Comment: is there a way for me to direct message you on a platform? I really need help

Comment: @WangWang what specifically do you need help with regarding this project?

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks for all of the help

Comment: @WangWang glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

**working zip function:**

```
for t in zip('123','456','789'):
  print(t)
```

> In the above example zip takes 3 strings as an argument.
>
> 1st iteration : when the first time "for" works, zip takes all first
>   elements from each three strings and return it as a tuple => ('1',
>   '4', '7')
>
> 2nd iteration zip returns = >  ('2', '5', '8')
>
> 3rd iteration zip returns => ('3', '6', '9')

```
for t in zip('123','456','789'):
  print(t)



('1', '4', '7')
('2', '5', '8')
('3', '6', '9')
```

**Going to your question**

s = ['hello','hullo','zeros']

```
*s => will unpack the list into 3 items. 

zip(*s) => zip('hello','hullo','zeros')

for t in zip(*s):

('h', 'h', 'z')
('e', 'u', 'e')
('l', 'l', 'r')
('l', 'l', 'o')
('o', 'o', 's')
```